# Request to reopen my question on sorting YouTube videos alphabetically in a playlist

Tags: support, closed-questions

I wrote [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/171751/sorting-youtube-videos-alphabetically-in-a-playlist?noredirect=1#comment160560_171751) on web applications and it was closed because it has been considered a duplicate. Actually my question is not about sorting playlists, but sorting videos inside a playlist. Could a moderator reopen it please?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148047/discussion-on-question-by-gennaro-arguzzi-request-to-reopen-my-question-on-sorti); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

The current close reason is:

> **Closed**. This question needs [details or clarity](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers. Closed 14 mins ago by [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n)**♦**.

I disagree with the close reason. The question is crystal-clear to me. The question does not need additional details or clarity. The question should be reopen. Unfortunately, I can't vote to reopen because the question is locked.

---

To address the comment that moderator [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) left:

> The question was returned to Super User. [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [16 mins ago](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/request-to-reopen-my-question-on-sorting-youtube-videos-alphabetically-in-a-play#comment5566_5098)

It'd be great if the mod could add why they returned the question to Super User. I don't  understand why the question was returned to Super User: the question is on-topic on WebApps and off-topic on Super User, so the migration rejection makes no sense to me.

Comment: A migrated question that is closed is automatically returned to the site that migrated it over.  If the question is improved it can still be reopened. 
 You are confusing understanding words with understanding the question the OP intends to ask.  I provided some examples in my answer to show how the question could be clarified.  From the OP's question, it would simply be guessing to have clarity on what they mean, regardless if all the words are understood.

Answer (score -1):

The close reason on your question is currently for details and clarity so my answer is based on that.

I didn't close your question but I'm happy to suggest some details you could add to improve your question.

> I'm wondering if it's possible to sort the videos in a youtube's playlist by name; so far I found only solutions to sort playlists alphabetically.

You could clarify what you already know about the basics of YouTube playlists, what you've have tried, and why it didn't solve your problem.

You could describe the problem space, for example how many videos, how frequently does the playlist change. Is it enough to sort it once, or once in a while?

Do you have a no idea how to sort playlist content or are you aware of the available options?

Do you already know that you can manually create any sort order you want for a playlist you own, be it alphabetical, by size, by second word?

Is the answer you are looking for a "How To" on sorting YouTube playlist content?

Are you looking beyond the included options for a solution using a script or extension that leverages Youtube's API?

Obviously I can only guess at the details of your specific situation but hope that gives you some ideas.

Comment: These details are not needed. They are extraneous details. If OP adds these details, do you promise to reopen the question? Or would you leave the question closed?

Comment: Why was the question subsequently moved to Super User if it lacked clarity or details?

Comment: @Flimm (1 of 4) I do invest time reviewing & reflecting before I post.  This is out of respect for the OP, the community, & my role.  Comments are not a great tool to make substantive points. Simply stating *“the details are not needed”* doesn’t make it so.  Further, stating details are *“extraneous”* presumes some knowledge of those details to be able to judge. (continued)

Comment: (2 of 4) My goal is for a question to provide enough detail that it can be answered, not simply that it can generate an answer.  It isn’t practical that we each assume different possibilities and post varied answers to possible questions based on a lack of detail.  The model isn’t to edit answers later once the specifics are known and/or delete ones that no longer apply.  Also, if we eventually understand the question to be off-topic the effort of any users who answered is then wasted. (continued)

Comment: (3 of 4) Sometimes we don’t know there are details missing because the OP provides detail but leaves out something significant.  Sometimes that is very frustrating and other times it can be adapted easily into the answer(s).   The OP did the right thing posting their meta question.  Following that they have not responded to any of the feedback, engaged with any mods regarding improving the question, nor edited their post. (continued)

Comment: (4 of 4) I’m not promising anything but I am also not playing a game to torture the OP with no intention of reopening a question.  The examples I gave in this meta answer are dead simple and low effort and serve to improve the question.

Comment: @Flimm *"Why was the question subsequently moved to Super User if it lacked clarity or details?"* per [my comment](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5098/5106?noredirect=1#comment5587_5099): `"A migrated question that is closed is automatically returned to the site that migrated it over. If the question is improved it can still be reopened"`