# Why are some discussions about question reopening hold in private chatrooms?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation, chat

I've recently noticed that some discussions about question reopening hold in private chatrooms.

Example 1:
[Reopen "What do the red dashed lines mean in Google Maps?"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/reopen-what-do-the-red-dashed-lines-mean-in-google-maps#comment5559_5090):

> This question (including the current answer) are being discussed privately with the OP and separately with the mod team. [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [Aug 18 at 14:37](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5090/reopen-what-do-the-red-dashed-lines-mean-in-google-maps#comment5559_5090)

Example 2: [Request to reopen my question on sorting YouTube videos alphabetically in a playlist](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/request-to-reopen-my-question-on-sorting-youtube-videos-alphabetically-in-a-play#comment5568_5098):

> **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148047/discussion-on-question-by-gennaro-arguzzi-request-to-reopen-my-question-on-sorti); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), or in [Web Applications Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). Comments continuing discussion may be removed. [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%c3%a9n) [yesterday](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/request-to-reopen-my-question-on-sorting-youtube-videos-alphabetically-in-a-play#comment5568_5098)

As [pppery](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/312586/pppery) [pointed out](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5098/request-to-reopen-my-question-on-sorting-youtube-videos-alphabetically-in-a-play#comment5569_5099):

> the chat room inexplicably made private.

Why are some discussions about question reopening hold in private chatrooms?

I thought such discussions should be public, since the community also has a say about question closures.

Comment: They are private for moderation reasons.

Answer (score 4):

With Example 1, the discussion was originally in a public room in Gallery mode (only mods and selected users can talk) with me ("the OP" referred to in the comment) and Rubén as participants. The discussion, however, quickly hit a wall since some of the relevant details (such as why some posts were locked) have to do with private stuff. I figured it would be a much more useful conversation if neither one of us was holding back, so I suggested having a private conversation instead. Making the room private was the fastest and easiest way to do that. (I'm a moderator on other sites so I can be privy to those details.) I did post a [summary of what I could](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64226994#64226994) from the chat.

As for Example 2, I wasn't involved in that chat at all and have no access to the room, so I can't answer that. However, assuming a second mod wasn't involved, it can't be the same reason as the first chat.